# Can a user doing a page refresh after a submit be a problem?

Tags: javascript, html

End users are often told not to hit the submit button twice, allowing the transaction to complete; and, there are different techniques used to address this situation.

Recently though, someone asked me, "what do you do to handle the situation of a user doing a page refresh after doing a submit", the implication being that this will cause a double submit or other problem.

Can you let me know if this is a real problem that needs to be handled ... what the situation is and how to best resolve it, if at all.

Comment: Most browsers will warn the user if the user is refreshing a form submission.

Comment: It can cause problems of such things like double posting, duplicate uploads etc. What you can do is attach a timestamp to the initial submit, and while validating any submit process, check to see if that user has recently submitted a form, say within the last hour (3600 seconds) either by IP reference or login reference. If so ignore the new submit and display an error or redirect, whichever you prefer. If this answers your question I can give an example if needed?

Comment: Fantastic Joe -- I think you got the exact issue / solution.

Comment: Joe, did you see beetrees solution?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a real problem unless you handle on your side. In practice on most browsers when the user hits refresh the data is resubmitted and if you on the server side do not check for this it would result in you taking the same action twice (e.g. charging a credit card twice, duplicate forum post et.c.).

The way to handle this is to check whether the user has previously done a post. For example, if you are building a forum you would send a hidden variable with a unique ID with the post. As you parse the posted data you save this unique ID into your database. If you ever encounter a post with a unique ID that has already been saved you know that you are looking at a "refresh" on the client side and you simply disregard the post.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beetree -- thanks.  This sounds very simple.  Any special cases to be aware of?  Looks like Joe (in comments to my question) uses a similar solution.  Thoughts / comments.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, there are other cases that you also need to consider. For example, people may hit the "back button". If you are doing posts they will be given a prompt, but if you are doing "GETs" it can cause a lot of problems.

For example, imagine that you have a "toggle" through a GET. The user hits the toggle, continues on to a new page then hits "back". This will hit your toggle functionality again and the user might not even notice. The same solution applies here with having IDs to make sure that you don't redo things.

Happy that you found my response helpful!

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you right, with posts one is "good".  I'm not getting the "toggle" on a GET  ..  can you give an example of a "toggle".  Appreciate all your insights ... very helpful / interesting.

Comment: No, you're not safe in either of the cases. You need to think it through. The toggle example would be a user flagging / unflagging a post and you handle this by sending the post id and "toggle" through GET, e.g. myscript.php?post_id={number}&toggle_flag

Answer (score 10):

The best way to resolve this is using the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Matt - thanks for this reference explaining the problem.  I'm still digesting it.  Did you see beetree's answer?

Comment: I still digesting this whole article, and also saw it said it doesn't handle all situations / problems.  Do you feel P/R/G has problems that beetree's solution does not? Unfortunately I'm still quite new to the whole HTTP 30X messaging stuff between clients and servers.

Comment: I disagree on this being the best way of handling it. If the user refreshes before the redirect goes through you would run the transaction twice.
IF you TRULY need to be careful you need to handle the logic of double posting on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

If your users are so inclined to do a page refresh, it sounds like you have a service taking *way* too long to respond. Disable the submit button on submit, and show some kind of loading indicator until the response comes back.

Alternatively, respond immediately on the server and queue the action for later. [Linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=f6714a8f9d0e52df08d2826fba60b0c37b845e34), for example, queues server behavior, rather than running immediately on "request to resize partition". You can generalize this approach for other behavior, and even show things like progress indicators and the like with ajax.

Comment: Stefan -- thanks for this comment.  Other comments / answers are very enlightening (for me).  Loading indicator also sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a real problem but I believe this is typically handled by the browser.  Chrome for instance will notify you on page refresh if there will be data posted to the server as a result, and give you the option of continuing or aborting.

EDIT:

Actually... come to think of it I did have to deal with this at work.  What I ended up doing was creating a shadow box over the page untill the process was complete to

1. give visual feedback that the process was working and
2. Prevent any other user actions.

Comment: or any page for that matter. The redirect is the important piece and is considered best practice.

Comment: well... I do think the community would agree. :) Ow well +1 from me then :)

Comment: Thanks Joseph -- I don't quite get it ... if the submit ends up being slow, is the problem even before they are redirected to another page, with them doing a refresh to try to speed things up.  Is there a browser independent way to do anything here?  The guy asking me the question, definitely implied there was (it was, in fact, an interview question I had :-)  ).

Comment: @Ray K Then in that case my edited answer sounds like what you need.  You can tell the interviewer that you would disable any further edits *and* give some kind of indication that the process was still working (e.g. the shadow box).

Comment: Joseph -- doesn't sound like this would prevent the user access to the refresh button, however.  Did you see some of the other answers, and the comment on my question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be a problem (and actually is a problem in a lot of websites).
But I think this is more of a server side related question than Javascript.
Best practice is to use [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern (since you are asking specific about refresh after submit).

Comment: Thanks Anthony -- this link says:  "The PRG pattern cannot address every scenario of duplicate form submission", as I'm still seeing to digest it all -- the various HTTP 30* messages. Did you see beetrees's response?  Sounds pretty simple.

Comment: @Ray, yes to timestamp / uniquely identify a operation and check it before doing server side processing is a proven method, but may require significant changes to your application. About the HTTP mechanics involved, It is all pretty much abstracted by the programing language, all you need to be concerned with is "redirecting after a post".PRG is only a best practice meant to prevent incidental "double posting", if you are concerned with malicious users and such you will have to dig deeper and do a lot of server side plumbing.

Comment: Got it -- cool.   I'm writing all the server stuff now, so I've got some options, but understanding this practice as first defense is useful.  Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

> "what do you do to handle the situation of a user doing a page refresh after doing a submit"

You should **redirect** to the page after a form is succesfully submitted.

This would prevent that the user submits the data again and prevents that anoying alert of the browser saying the data will be submitted again.